# What is the best way to display multiple columns?

Tags: usability, layout, desktop-application, grid, multi-column

I have been asked to come up with a solution for displaying 50+ columns that were  **previously viewed in excel**  and now need to be brought to the desktop application UI. Mobile version is out of scope.

Comment: Can you expand on this? What are the problems? What's wrong with just replicating like-for-like on the application? We need more information here about what the actual problem is that you need help with.

Comment: Is the issue trying to display ALL 50+ columns on the screen? Or do you want to know the best method for letting the user know there are additional columns off the screen?

Comment: Hi all...thanks for the quick reply and here is some more info. Because this data was previously viewed in excel, the user has a minimum expectation  to have a decent span of large columns of data at low zoom. So essentially my question is around displaying as much as possible at a time...I know there are several options around displaying columns as a group, etc. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

- Identify the columns that would likely to show first
- Add big arrow at the right page (center of the page not at the bottom corner) '>', when user clicks - show remained columns
- Freeze 1st or few left columns to get connect information with other columns when user click '>'
- Add link / button at the bottom of the cell text if you find too much content not to be shown at first. By clicking the link / button can expand to reveal the remaining content of the cell.
- Include truncated text if its understandable to reduce space
- Keep in mind that, clicking big '>' should not be replaced the page, it should just replace the table content
- Make sure, user will never lose the connectivity / continuity between the columns